Reading compass and play sounds while in background
For a capacitor or Cordova app.
While the app is in the background, for example when the phone is locked, I need the app to keep getting updates of the gps and compass so that it plays a spatial sound coming from a specific geo location.. (like a radar sound coming from a virtual beacon ).
I've seen some plugins for background GPS, but could not find anything for background compass and background spatial audio ...
How would you do it ?
Or it is too much for an hybrid? (Better RN, Flutter or traditional native app?)
